# Using a function for the table name

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql

I have a set of 4 tables that contain different partitions of some data. I also have a plpgsql function that will take an id and return the name of the table containing that data as a 'character varying'.

However, when I try to use this function to select from the correct table, e.g.

```
SELECT f.a FROM getTable(someID) AS f;
```

it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw an error on the SELECT, but it doesn't return the fields I'm expecting either (i.e. it says f.a doesn't exist).

**How do I select data from a table where the table name is given by the return of a function?**

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1. This is going to be run over millions of records, so I don't want to have to do it as two separate calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for the problem described in the topic you should use [**inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) with tables.

Answering the question - use ***execute***:

```
execute "SELECT f.a FROM " || getTable(someID) || " AS f";
```

Comment: I agree that using inheritance for this would be the way to go. But, when doing that you'll want to turn on the `constraint_exclusion` setting in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: @qqx - to be precise, `constraint_exclusion` should be set to `partition`

Comment: It should be set to at least `partition`. `on` would also work, but may cause other queries to be slower. But I now see that `partition` is the default value for 9.1, that's changed since I last used partitioning.

Comment: I used inheritance in the end. I don't think execute would have worked because, and admittedly I didn't mention this, the SELECT was a nested SELECT.